# vaadin 8 ComboBox : removeAllValidators

Tags: combobox, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

In vaadin 7 `com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox` there was `removeAllValidators()`.
Is there a replacement for `removeAllValidators()` in vaadin 8?

Answer (score 1):

In Vaadin 8, and also in subsequent Vaadin 10,14, versions validator API is not directly in the fields anymore. Instead Vaadin 8 introduced a new concept called [Binder](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html), which handles data binding with Validator - Converter chain.

With Binder you can form the Validator - Converter chain using builder pattern, see example below

```
binder.forField(yearOfBirthField)
  // Validator will be run with the String value of the field
  .withValidator(text -> text.length() == 4,
    "Doesn't look like a year")
  // Converter will only be run for strings with 4 characters
  .withConverter(
    new StringToIntegerConverter("Must enter a number"))
  // Validator will be run with the converted value
  .withValidator(year -> year >= 1900 && year < 2000,
    "Person must be born in the 20th century")
  .bind(Person::getYearOfBirth, Person::setYearOfBirth);
```

The rough equivalent to old Vaadin 7, field.removeAllValidators() is

```
binder.removeBinding(yearOfBirthField);
```

The Binder is typed with Bean, which you use with your form. If you have only a single field, then Binder may be an overkill, and you may use [FieldBinder](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/fieldbinder) add-on.